NestJs Linter problem , LF and CRLF problem
I wanted to learn nestjs and I followd the documentation to create a simple project , did nest new project-name and creted a new project , when I open it on vscode I got a lint project saying this

I asked the question on nestjs community on discord and the solutions didnt work , Idk how to solve the problem , this is ennoythin runnning the npm run lint each time to fix the linter , help please

I tried doing the npm run lint , this fix the problem for existing files but not for the new ones ( annoying)
I tried git config --global core.autocrlf false didnt work
I tried changing the settings in vscode also didnt work

You could run npm run lint -- --fix and it should fix any autofixable issues, including Windows carriage returns.

@moonstar-x running the npm run lint -- --fix will fix already existing files , but when I create a new file , the problem persists , should I run the command each time? thats painfull isnt it?

You could actually: enable automatic linting on-save and/or change line endings in vscode

I was able to fix this issue by adding this to rules in .eslintrc.js
'prettier/prettier': ['error', { endOfLine: 'auto' }],

hope it helps
